# Login to OWA programmatically using saml token

Tags: exchange-server, adfs, outlook-web-app

There is a standard way to authorize to OWA using ADFS. I need to repeat it programmatically from a custom web site. I know how I can get a saml token from ADFS, but I don't know how post it to OWA. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to customize the AD FS login page for it. The good article is over [there](http://ea-code.com/Blog/Detail?id=2&author=Eugen%20Goroluov%20&date=February%2020,2017).